# plesk 11 centos 6 how to configure what is recorded in the apache access log?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd

How do you modify plesk/apache so that it does not log access logs for resources like .png .ico rather than pages? -ie .php .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Conditional Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog) section.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.png|\.ico)$" dontlog
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```